Dead, rotten, and moldy Phalaenopsis roots
My Phalaeonopsis appeared to have overgrown its original flexible plastic pot:

These are the roots of the plant after I removed the pot:


Unfortunately, it seems that the roots are unhealthy. Some look dead, others look rotten. There is green mold, and the media is mushy.
What should I now do to re-pot the plant? Do I remove all the media and cut off all the brown/yellow roots?

Are you sure the roots are bad, since they look green to white, all good colors? Softness is the problem. Also, are you fixed on replanting in plastic , not clay?

@YosefBaskin I am open to any method of replanting that could prevent the same problems in the future.

Urgh, looks like rot from too much standing water in the pot. All I can recommend is removing the dead/dying roots and keeping it drier, preferably in a pot with drainage holes so water can't pool in the bottom.
